# Wrap & Unwrap WETH, error when exceeds a value

Tags: solidity, remix

I have smart contract who can unwrap WETH to ETH and wrap ETH to WETH with function start.
[image]
i send to my smart contract 0.01 WETH and call function start with 1000000000000000 (wei) in parameters. everything is good. I change value: 2000000000000000 (wei), remix give me error:
[image]

What's wrong ?